# Is this a pure function in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Below function `getRandomString` generates a random String from a List of characters :

```
  def genRandomInt(lb: Int, ub: Int) = {
    val rnd = new scala.util.Random
    lb + rnd.nextInt(ub)
  }     
  def getRandomString(validChars: List[Char]) = {

    val size = validChars.size

    val random = new scala.util.Random
    val stringBuilder = new StringBuilder
    val rnd = genRandomInt(0, size)
    val sb = new StringBuilder

    for (i <- 0 to size - 1) {
      val rnd = genRandomInt(0, size)
      sb.append(validChars(rnd))
    }

    sb.toString
  }                                               //> getRandomString: (validChars: List[Char])String

    val rs = getRandomString(('a' to 'j').toList)
                                                  //> rs  : String = aghdjjhjge
```

Is `getRandomString` an example of a pure function as it does not modify state ?

Comment: "if its argument does not change between multiple calls then its result will not change." – Can you show an example of that? I am pretty sure that's not true, but I can't test it because your code doesn't compile.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag your right the result will change, ive removed this sentence. This code is not referential transparent. This code compiles for me in worksheet using Eclipse Kepler Scala version 2.11

Comment: `error: not found: value genRandomInt`. This seems to be a method from a Scala MATLAB binding? But I don't have MATLAB.

Comment: @JörgWMittag genRandomInt method posted

Comment: `genRandomInt` is also not pure, so even if it weren't for the reasons pointed out below, `getRandomString` would *still* not be pure by the simple fact that it calls a non-pure function. Impurity is infectious.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, because it does in fact modify state. `new scala.util.Random` ultimately invokes `new java.util.Random`, which accesses and modifies a static (i.e. global), mutable `AtomicLong` called `seedUniquifier`. And therefore if this method is called multiple times then the result will change.

This is a good example of how innocent-seeming methods can hide accesses to global mutable state, which would be forbidden in a stricter functional language like Haskell (though that approach comes with its own problems).

Answer (score 2):

No because `new scala.util.Random().nextInt ...` returns something different each time, which is cogently explained by Imm.

Nevertheless you can simply pass in a seed then it will be a pure function because it will return the same random string every time. You could add the seed as a parameter or just fix it inside the random string method.

Finally, I've noticed you have written a huge amount of code to generate a random String.  I suggest you look at ScalaCheck which has stacks of useful functions for generating random stuff (for unit tests), `String` comes out-of-box.

If you don't want to pull in a library, you can still make that code much more concise:

```
def randomString(fromChars: List[Char], length: Int): String = {
  val rand = new Random(1234) // Now it's pure functional because the seed is fixed
  val fromCharsSize = fromChars.size // to save us repeatedly counting
  List.fill(length)(fromChars(rand.nextInt(fromCharsSize))).mkString
}
```

Observe it returns same value every time

```
scala> randomString("asdf".toList, 10)
res0: String = dsfafssdsa

scala> randomString("asdf".toList, 10)
res1: String = dsfafssdsa
```